# Burning Raspbian to SD card from a Mac laptop

Tags: raspbian, sd-card, operating-systems

I have a Raspberry Pi 1 Model A and would like to use [Etcher](https://etcher.io/) to burn a [Raspbian image](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/) to an SD card, so that I can plug that SD card into my pi and use it to load Raspbian as its OS.

I'm not terribly familiar with SD cards: according to their [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Digital) there are SD cards, mini SD, micro SD, SDHC, SDXC, etc... I'm wondering what version my pi needs.

To make things a little more complicated, I only have a MacBook Pro laptop, so I'd need to (if this is possible) burn the Raspbian image onto the SD card from my Mac...and it doesn't look like my Mac has any SD slots (I see HDMI, USB and the Mac dongle ports though). Does anybody know if Apple makes any dongles/converters that would allow me to attach my SD card to it?

Basically I'm wondering what hardware setup I'll need for my Mac and what type of SD card I'll need to work with my pi model.

Comment: What Mac? If it doesn't have a SD Slot (the latest don't) buy a generic USB adapter; they cost as little as $6

Comment: Thanks @Milliways (+1) - maybe something [like this](https://www.amazon.com/WEme-Compact-Compatible-Smartphones-Supports/dp/B00GQPVVV0/ref=sr_1_3?ie=UTF8&qid=1504087402&sr=8-3&keywords=usb+sd+converter) maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Raspberry Pi 1 uses standard SD card, but you can get a SD - micro SD adapter included sometimes when you buy micro SD cards.

A SD card of Class 10 and 8GB is recommended.

Regarding MAC and USB-SD card adapters so should any generic adapter work.

Ref.:

https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/installation/sd-cards.md

http://elinux.org/RPi_SD_cards

Comment: Thanks so much @MatsK (+1) - do you foresee any potential issues stemming from Raspbian being burned on a Mac but used by pi hardware?

Comment: Noop, I have several friends with MAC's and I haven't heard any problems and some even use $1 USB SD card adapters from china.